# Discrepancy in values between Summed Line Lengths and Clip in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, clip, statistics

**I have**

- a polygon vector layer containing four polygons, corresponding to four Protected Areas in a state in India.
- a line vector corresponding to all the rivers in that state.

---

**Desired output:** I want to find out the proportion of the total river length flowing through Protected Areas.

---

**Results so far:**

1. I tried using `'Sum Line Lengths'` under Vector Analysis to get at this, and then used the `'Basic Statistics for Numeric Tools'` to get the summed length of all the rivers falling within the Protected Areas, by putting the river layer in the `'Lines'` layer and the Protected Area layer in the `'Polygons'` layer, in the `'Sum Line Lengths'` dialog box. The value I got was `368.62 km`.

However, the new layer looks the same as the polygon layer of Protected Areas in the workspace, so I decided to use `'Clip'` as well, where the river layer was the Input layer and the  Protected Area layer was the Clip layer.

2. I then ran a `'$length'` operation on the field calculator to get the length of all the river segmens, and then used the `'Basic Statistics for Numeric Tools'` to get the summed lengths. Now I'm getting a value of `552.33 km`.

I'm a little confused with this, as I was assuming I should get the same value for both. Does the `'Sum Line Lengths'` work differently than a straight up `'Clip'`?